# Change the position of div on page refresh using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 `div`'s, by default I'm showing `1 2 3`. On each refresh the div position has to change like:

- 1-2-3
- 2-3-1
- 3-1-2
- ...

Comment: Considered using a cookie to store the positions and then increment on page loads?

Comment: If you're actually refreshing the page from the server why would you not have the server change the DIV order? Please provide more details.

Comment: the order of div at every refresh is random ?

Comment: @MichaelSwan - It seems like the first item is put to the end of the list, after each refresh

Comment: Maybe it's about Tower of Hanoi :P

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">DIV1</div>
    <div id="div2">DIV2</div>
    <div id="div3">DIV3</div>
</div>
<button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
```

**Pure JS:** http://jsfiddle.net/CKCpb/1/

```
var chain = [
    document.getElementById("div1"),
    document.getElementById("div2"),
    document.getElementById("div3")
],
wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper"),
refresh = document.getElementById("refresh");

refresh.onclick = function() {
    chain.push( chain.shift() );
    for ( var i=0, len = chain.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        var el = chain[i];
        wrapper.removeChild(el);
        wrapper.appendChild(el);
    };
};
```

**And the jQuery solution:** http://jsfiddle.net/CKCpb/2/

```
var $wrapper = $("#wrapper"),
    $refresh = $("#refresh");

$refresh.bind("click", function() {
    $($wrapper.children()[0])
        .appendTo($wrapper);
});
```

Comment: This is not a solution using jQuery as the question states.

Comment: Lol. is this question even for real? ... No code, no engagement.. :)

Comment: @Darth - It's a solution using javascript though. Why use jQuery if its not needed?

Comment: @Curt Well first of all, almost nobody uses raw JavaScript, there's no reason to do it. And more importantly, if the question is about jQuery solution, than the answer should be a jQuery solution. That's like if somebody asked how to implement singleton in C++ and you gave him Java code.

Comment: what...? is the same language. And it will work together. ?? ! Anyway i make the jQuery way...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

HTML:

```
<div class="divs">
    <div>DIV1</div>
    <div>DIV2</div>
    <div>DIV3</div>
</div>
<button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
```

JS:

```
$("#refresh").click(function(e) { 
  var div = $(".divs div:first").remove();
  $(".divs").append(div);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NJJbe/

Comment: no need to remove if you are appending it again. You don't clone the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['pos']))
    $_SESSION['pos'] = 1;
else {
    if ($_SESSION['pos'] == 3)
        $_SESSION['pos'] = 1;
    else
        $_SESSION['pos']++;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var position = <?php echo $_SESSION['pos']; ?>;
for (var i=0;i<(position-1);$i++) {
    var div = $(".divs div:first").remove();
    $(".divs").append(div);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divs">
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2</div>
    <div>div 3</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```